# mongodb find between given time irrespective of date

Tags: mongodb

Below query will give all user who logged in between `1-AUG-2018`, **6AM** to `1-AUG-2018`, **8AM**. Is there any way to find users who log-in between say **6AM** to **8AM** irrespective of date. In other words all user who log-in to any date but the time should be between `6AM-8AM`.

```
db.user.find({
   "log-time" : {"$gte": ISODate("2018-08-1T00:06:00.000Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-08-05T08:00:00.000Z")}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable which will contain `hour` extracted from `ISODate` using [$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) and then you can apply your conditions in `$match` inside [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { hour: { $hour: "$log-time" } },
                    in: {
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: [ "$$hour", 6 ] },
                            { $lt: [ "$$hour", 8 ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: can you please let us know how can add minutes too while searching?

Comment: in case you just want to compare minutes you can use `$minute` which returns a value between 0 and 59. If you want for instance log-time > 5:30 then you can use `$hour` and `$minute` to calculate minutes after midnight (60*hour+minute)  and then compare such values. Lemme know if you need clarification on this